# Minimum jumps to reach end when some points are blocked

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

A person is currently at `(0,0)` and wants to reach `(X,0)` and he has to jump a few steps to reach his house.From a point say `(a,0)`, he can jump to either `(a + k1,0)` i.e forward of `k1` steps or he can jump`(a-k2,0)` i.e backward jump of `k2` steps. The first jump he takes must be forward.Also,he cannot jump backward twice consecutively.But he can jump any no of continuous forward jump.There are n points `a1,a2 upto an` where he cannot jump.

I have to determine minimum no of jumps to reach his house or to conclude that he cannot reach his house. If he can reach house print yes and specify no. of jumps If not print no.

Here

```
X = location of persons house.
N = no. of points where he cannot jump.
k1 = forward jump.
k2 = backward jump.
```

example

For inputs

```
X=6 N=2 k1=4 k2=2

Blocked points = 3 5

the answer is 3 (4 to 8 to 6 or 4 to 2 to 6)
```

For input

```
6 2 5 2

1 3
```

the person cannot reach his house

```
N can be upto 10^4 and X can be upto 10^5
```

I thought of using dynamic programming but i'm not able to implement it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do these points have y coordinates if they are always 0?

Comment: @kaya3 doesn't matter. ignore them

Comment: Can you share the problem link?

Answer (score 1):

I think your direction of using dynamic programming can work but I will show another way to solve the question with the same asymptotic time complexity as dynamic programming would achieve.

This question can be described as a problem in graphs where you have `X` nodes indexed `1` to `X` and these is an edge between every `a` and `a + k1`, `b` and `b - k2`, where you remove the nodes in `N`.
This will be enough if you can jump backward how many times you would like but you cannot jump twice in a row so you can add the following modification: Duplicate the graph's nodes, duplicate also the forward going edges but make them go from the duplicated to the original, now make all of the backward going edges to go to the duplicated graph. Now every backward edge will send you to the duplicated and you will not be able to take a backward edge again until you will go to the original using a forward going edge. This will make sure that after a backward edge you will always take a forward edge - so you will not be able to jump forward twice.

Now finding the shortest path from `1` to `X` is like finding smallest number of jumps since edge is a jump.

Finding the shortest path in directed unweighted graph takes `O(|V|+|E|)` time and memory (using [`BFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)), your graph has `2 * X` as `|V|` and also the number of edges will be `2 * 2 * X` so time and memory complexity of `O(X)`.

If you can jump backward twice you use the `networkx` library in python for a simple demo (you can also use if for complicated demo):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

X = 6
N = 2
k1 = 4
k2 = 2

nodes = [0, 1, 2, 4, 6]

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)

for n in nodes:
    if n + k1 in nodes:
        G.add_edge(n, n + k1)
    if n - k2 in nodes:
        G.add_edge(n, n - k2)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
plt.plot()
plt.show()

path = nx.shortest_path(G, 0, X)
print(f"Number of jumps: {len(path) - 1}. path: {str(path)}")
```

Comment: Does this answer consider an example like k1=3, k2=4, X=2, where the solution could be to go back to -1, then up to 2?

Comment: No @גלעדברקן , but assuming `k1` and `k2` smaller than `X` and `N` contains only nodes between `0` and `X`, you can add `X` nodes from left and right.

Comment: How does this answer take into account the restriction, "cannot jump backward twice consecutively?"

Comment: @Yonlif How do i duplicate the nodes? can you add an implementation in c++ or c?

Comment: @Klasen you should probably use גלעדברקן's code. I can write it in c++ if you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Would a breadth-first search be efficient enough?

Something like this? (Python code)

```py
from collections import deque

def f(x, k1, k2, blocked):
  queue = deque([(k1, 0, None, None)])

  while (queue):
    (p, depth, direction, prev) = queue.popleft()

    if p in blocked or (x + k2 < p < x - k1): # not sure about these boundaries ... ideas welcome
      continue

    if p == x:
      return depth

    blocked.add(p) # visited

    queue.append((p + k1, depth + 1, "left", direction))

    if prev != "right":
      queue.append((p - k2, depth + 1, "right", direction))

X = 6
k1 = 4
k2 = 2
blocked = set([3, 5])
print f(X, k1, k2, blocked)

X = 2
k1 = 3
k2 = 4
blocked = set()
print f(X, k1, k2, blocked)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of גלעדברקן in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int id;
    int depth;
    int direction; // 1 is left, 0 is right
};

int BFS(int start, int end, int k1, int k2, bool blocked[], int length)
{
    queue<node> q;
    blocked[0] = true;
    q.push({start, 0, 0});

    while(!q.empty())
    {
        node f = q.front();
        q.pop();

        if (f.id == end) {
            return f.depth;
        }

        if(f.id + k1 < length and !blocked[f.id + k1])
        {
            blocked[f.id + k1] = true;
            q.push({f.id + k1, f.depth + 1, 0});
        }
        if (f.direction != 1) { // If you just went left - don't go left again
            if(f.id - k2 >= 0 and !blocked[f.id - k2])
            {
                blocked[f.id - k2] = true;
                q.push({f.id - k2, f.depth + 1, 1});
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}


int main() {
    bool blocked[] = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
    std::cout << BFS(0, 6, 4, 2, blocked, 7) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can control on the length of the steps, the start and end, and the blocked nodes.